# Trying to pass an object to another class

Tags: c++

I'm trying to pass an object to another cpp class to reuse it.

Object created here. I'm putting int for this sample, but it's linked to another class with functions to use for the object.
**InitHeader.h**

```
int Object;
```

I call the other class function, trying to pass it the Object made.

**InitClass.cpp**

```
CalledHeader::call(&Object);
Object.run();
```

Setting up the call function

**CalledHeader.h**

```
void call(int Object);
```

Trying to receive the Object in call(), and wanting to reuse it in AnotherFunction() with the same address used in the call Object.run() above.

**CalledClass.cpp**

```
void CalledHeader::call(int Object) {
  unlock_a_mutex;
}

void CalledHeader::AnotherFunction() {
  ReuseObject.aCall();
}
```

I can't seem to pass the object currently, getting cannot call member function without object with this sample above. I'm lost at the moment.

Comment: Provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @RemyLebeau Have tried calling with &Object, updated it above. No luck yet.

Comment: @Jacob in your example, you are passing a type of `int*` to that function, because `&Object` is a pointer. Read a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) about some basics before asking such trivia here please!!

Answer (score 1):

Read up about [**references**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference) and [**pointers**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer). Right now, you are passing the object into `CalledHeader::call()` **by value**, which will *make a copy* of the object, and you are not storing that copy anywhere that `AnotherFunction()` can reach it.

Since you say you want to "*reuse it in `AnotherFunction()` **with the same address** used in the call `Object.run()`*", a *copy* won't suit your needs, so you need a pointer/reference instead.

Try something like this:

```
class objectClass {
public:
    void run();
};
```

```cpp
class CalledHeader {
    objectClass *mObject;
public:
    void call(objectClass *Object);
    void AnotherFunction();
};
```

```cpp
void CalledHeader::call(objectClass *Object) {
    mObject = Object;
}

void CalledHeader::AnotherFunction() {
    mObject->run();
}
```

```cpp
objectClass Object;
CalledHeader hdr;
hdr.call(&Object);
hdr.AnotherFunction();
```